# Customer save event

Tags: magento2

I want to save a custom attribute value in my custom table after saving a customer from the admin panel, with an observer event,
I only need the name of the event

Comment: When you want this observer at time of customer creation or customer save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `customer_save_after` and eventually check if the action comes from admin if that's required

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried to find out the event during customer creation at Magento, then you can use  `adminhtml_customer_save_after` event.

> ```
>             $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
>                 'adminhtml_customer_save_after',
>                 ['customer' => $customer, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
>             );
> ```

That this event, you get  custom field data using `$observer->getRequest()->getPostValue();` if you will add any custom field ***admin customer  create and edit page.***

**Observer look Like:**

```
<?php

namespace {VendorName}\{ModuelName}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveFromBackend implements ObserverInterface
{


    /**
     * Save A customer Annual Purchase Limit
     *
     * @param  Observer $observer
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $postData = $request->getPostValue();

        if (isset($postData['custom_field']))
        ) {
        $customfield = $postData['custom_field'];
            // Save data here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `customer_save_commit_after` event as this is triggered after the transaction is committed.